# Writing non-ASCII characters to file in pandas python

Tags: python, csv, non-ascii-characters

I have a list like this:

```
a = ['olivsortiment utan kärna', 'perunajauho', 'chili extrakt','Keitetty herkullisista äyriäisistä', 'SOIJAKASTIKEJAUHE', 'Rypsisiemenöljy']
```

So there are non-ascii characters in the elements of the list including ö, ä, Ö, and Ä. I am using pandas dataframe to print this into csv using following code.

```
frame = pd.Dataframe(a)
frame.to_csv('path', sep=',', encoding = 'utf-8')
```

It prints the dataframe correctly but non-ascii characters are not correctly printed. They are showing some weird characters. I am already encoding it to 'utf-8' but still it does not print correctly.
The first element `a[0]` for example written in csv file is `olivsortiment utan kÃ¤rna`. So it replace `ä` by `Ã¤`. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: How are you reading that CSV file? It looks like your reader is assuming the file is encoded with Latin1, you need to tell it that the file uses UTF-8. `u'kärna'` encodes to UTF-8 as `b'k\xc3\xa4rna' ` but if those bytes are decoded as Latin 1 you get `kÃ¤rna`

Comment: Thanks. you were right. There was a problem with encoding to latin-1